# Access hbase remotely

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am using the hbase java api to connect to hbase remotely, but when I executed the code, I got `MasterNotRunningException`. When I debugged the code, I came to know that zookeeper was returning the address of hmaster as localhost, so the client was trying to search for the hmaster locally. When I changed the `/etc/hosts` file the entry as:

```
<ip of the master> localhost
```

then it worked fine.

However, I think that this is not the right way. I think I have to change the addresses somewhere in the configuration of zookeeper, but I did not get it.

Comment: This might help: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup

Comment: Is the property `hbase.cluster.distributed` set to `ture` in `hbase-site.xml`?

Comment: sorry @Nanda that didn't work out

Answer (score 1):

Hbase register automatically to ZK so you don' have to configure it there. 
Use Master IP address instead of "localhost" to avoid further troubleshoots